# Jquery send_to_editor Not Working For Wordpress 3.3

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am using a shortcode generator in the wordpress admin area to easily create peges. I have a form there with a send button which using send_to_editor jquery to sent the data in the wordpress editor.

All was working till I updated the wordpress version to 3.3 new one.

Any ideas?...

Answer (score 0):

Trying to figure this out as well.

In the interim, this works;

```
jQuery( edCanvas ).val( jQuery( edCanvas ).val() + yourHtml );
```

But, it does not respect the caret position, but could probably be hacked to do so.

This also works;

```
edInsertContent(edCanvas, yourHtml);
```

That respects caret position, but jumps the window about.